# Java Contar caracter distinto de una palabra

Tags: java, array, string

Se como contar los caracteres de una palabra pero no sé como hacer que no se repita si ese carácter ya se contó

La salida que pretendo sacar seria de una entrada de "RATA", una salida de 
R 1, A 2, T 1.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadena="";
        char [] Arraycadena ;
        char caracter;
        int contador =0;
        System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
        cadena=Leer.dato();
        Arraycadena=cadena.toCharArray();
        for(int i =0;i<Arraycadena.length;i++){
            caracter = Arraycadena[i];
            for(int j=0;j<Arraycadena.length;j++){
                if(Arraycadena[j]==caracter){
                    contador++;
                }//Fin Si
            }//Fin Para
            System.out.println(Arraycadena[i]+" "+contador+" veces.");
            contador= 0;
        }//Fin Para

    }

}
```

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres hacer es contar las letras distintas de una palabra?

Comment: Si, exacto, perdona por mi mal explicación

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tengo una mejor respuesta a esta pregunta, pero no la escribiré hasta que no expliques bien lo que quieres (aún así, no sé si me anime a escribirla, dado que tu requerimiento es confuso). En cuanto @PabloSimonDiEstefano hizo su acertado comentario debiste haber editado el título y la explicación de la pregunta. Como ha ocurrido, tu mal planteamiento ha llevado a respuestas que finalmente no eran lo que buscabas. Considera que aquí la gente invierte su tiempo para ayudarte, por lo tanto, sé claro en lo que expones. Gracias.

Comment: Sabrían como hacerlo pero contando también los espacios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres contar cuantas veces aparece cada letra puedes mirar si esta ya existía y, si existía, sumarlo a un array donde guardes cuantas veces aparece. Por lo que tendrías un array de booleanos para ver si ya existe y otro de integers para ver la cantidad de veces que aparece.

Siguiendo tu código lo que buscas es algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena="";
    char [] Arraycadena ;
    char caracter;
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
    cadena=Leer.dato();
    Arraycadena=cadena.toCharArray();

    boolean[] yaEstaElCaracter = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
    int[] cuantasVeces = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE];

    for(int i =0;i<Arraycadena.length;i++){
        caracter = Arraycadena[i];            
        if(Arraycadena[i]==caracter){
            cuantasVeces[caracter]++;
        }
        yaEstaElCaracter[caracter] = true;
    }//Fin Para


    for(int i = 0; i < yaEstaElCaracter.length; i++){
        if(yaEstaElCaracter[i])
            System.out.println((char) i +" "+cuantasVeces[i]+" veces.");
    }

}
```

### EDICION:

Para mostrarlos por orden se me ocurre una solucion menos elegante, y es que recorras el array hacia delante y vayas eliminando las letras que ya hayan aparecido e insertando un caracter que nunca debe aparecer (por ejemplo el espacio en blanco y así puede servirte también para contar caracteres de una frase).

Quedaria asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena="";
    char [] Arraycadena ;
    char caracter;
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
    cadena=Leer.dato();
    Arraycadena=cadena.toCharArray();

    char[] caracteres = new char[cadena.length()];
    int[] cuantasVeces = new int[cadena.length()];

    for(int i =0;i<Arraycadena.length;i++){
        caracter = Arraycadena[i];   
        caracteres[i] = caracter;
        for(int j = i; j < Arraycadena.length; j++)   {                  
            if(Arraycadena[j]==caracter){
                cuantasVeces[i]++;
                Arraycadena[j] = ' ';
            }
        }    
        if(caracteres[i] != ' ')
            System.out.println(caracteres[i] +" "+cuantasVeces[i]+" veces.");
    }

}
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
Entrada: 
    RATA
Salida:
    R 1 veces.
    A 2 veces.
    T 1 veces.
```

Ejemplo con una frase:

```
Entrada:
    TARTA DE RATA
Salida: 
    T 3 veces.
    A 4 veces.
    R 2 veces.
    D 1 veces.
    E 1 veces.
```

Comment: Guao, si eso es lo que quería, ya para colmo sería que lo sacase ordenado por orden, como RATA R 1, A 2, T 1

Comment: Te lo dejo arriba editado.

Comment: Tremendo muchas gracias Wyrncael

Answer (score 3):

Este es un ejemplo que tengo implementado en un programa para hacer lo que buscas:

```
public class MiClase {

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          int res = ContarCharUnicos("aaeiou");
          System.out.println(res);
      }

      // Función para contar los caracteres únicos en una cadena
      public static int ContarCharUnicos(String input) {
          boolean[] comprobarChar = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
          for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
              comprobarChar[input.charAt(i)] = true;
          }

          int cuenta = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < comprobarChar.length; i++) {
              if (comprobarChar[i] == true){
                  cuenta++;
              }
          }

          return cuenta;
      }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que busco es por ejemplo : "RATA" que tenga una salida de R 1 , A 2 , T 1

Comment: @user7407723 eso no es lo que pusiste en tu pregunta. si es asi, por favor aclaralo en la pregunta, poniendo un ejemplo de lo que queres.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar, una implementacion basada en Map:

```
String str = "una cadena con muchas letras repetidas";

Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
    if(map.containsKey(c)) {
        map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(c, 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(map);
//{u=2, n=3, a=6,  =5, c=3, d=2, e=4, o=1, m=1, h=1, s=3, l=1, t=2, r=2, p=1, i=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función me devuelve la cantidad de caracteres unicos en Javascript.

```
function ContarCharUnicos(input) {
    var cadenanueva="";
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(!cadenanueva.includes(input.charAt(i))){
            cadenanueva+=input.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    return cadenanueva.length;
}
```